# invalid column name when trying to pass the result for another calculation

Tags: sql-server

i am trying to pass my result from profilhøjde down to a calculation for procent and then show the id(`[Dækstørelsen]`) and filtrering it but i get a

> invalid column name for both [Dækstørelsen] and "procent for 10 Tommer"

how do i do this?

```
/******calculation for profilhøjde******/
       select 
      ("profilhøjde" *2 + @diameter10)*PI() as "diameter 10 tommer" 
      from
        (select ([brede]*[Profil])/100 as "profilhøjde"
        from [Tabel].[dæk]
        )a
    /******calculation for procent******/
           select 
           [Dækstørelsen],CAST(CEILING(
    (@omkredsnu-"diameter 10 tommer")/@omkredsnu*100*100)/100 
    as decimal(18,2)) as "procent for 10 Tommer"

      from
       (select ("profilhøjde" *2 + @diameter10)*PI() as "diameter 10 tommer" 
        from [Tabel].[dæk]
        )b
         where "procent for 10 Tommer"  BETWEEN @negativværdi AND @maxafvigelsværdi
    SET @negativværdi = Concat('-', @maxafvigelsværdi);
```

i had used this before

```
 select * from
(select [Dækstørelsen],CAST(CEILING(
(@omkredsnu-[Omkreds for 10 Tommer])/@omkredsnu*100*100)/100 
as decimal(18,2)) as "procent for 10 Tommer"
from [Tabel].[dæk]
)a
where "procent for 10 Tommer"  BETWEEN @negativværdi AND @maxafvigelsværdi
```

Comment: Your procent for 10 Tommer does not seem to be part of any table

Comment: thats right is a alias in the calculation for procent

Comment: You cannot use an alias in a where clause.

Comment: i had used it in a similar way

Comment: This is not the same. In the previous way it is an alias in a subselect. In the question, it is an alias in the main select.

Comment: If the last query works, why do you want to change it at all?

Comment: what is the corret way to do it if i can't do it this way?
thats becuase i already had some premaded results for it in the column [Omkreds for 10 Tommer] but i wan't to have it to do the whole calculation instead

Comment: So `[Omkreds for 10 Tommer` should be `"diameter 10 tommer"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if you remove the alias

```
 select 
      ("profilhøjde" *2 + @diameter10)*PI() as "diameter 10 tommer" 
      from
        (select ([brede]*[Profil])/100 as "profilhøjde"
        from [Tabel].[dæk]
        )a
    /******calculation for procent******/
           select 
           [Dækstørelsen],CAST(CEILING(
    (@omkredsnu-"diameter 10 tommer")/@omkredsnu*100*100)/100 
    as decimal(18,2)) as "procent for 10 Tommer"

      from
       (select ("profilhøjde" *2 + @diameter10)*PI() as "diameter 10 tommer" 
        from [Tabel].[dæk]
        )b
         where CAST(CEILING(
    (@omkredsnu-"diameter 10 tommer")/@omkredsnu*100*100)/100 
    as decimal(18,2))  BETWEEN @negativværdi AND @maxafvigelsværdi
    SET @negativværdi = Concat('-', @maxafvigelsværdi);
```

Comment: [Dækstørelsen] is still invalid

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error messages are

- `[Dækstørelsen]` is not a column in the subselect, but in table `[Tabel].[dæk]`
- `"procent for 10 Tommer"` is an alias in the select and is therefore not allowed in the where clause

To fix the first error, you must include the column in your subselect, e.g.

```
select [Dækstørelsen],
       ("profilhøjde" * 2 + @diameter10) * PI() as "diameter 10 tommer" 
from (select [Dækstørelsen], ([brede] * [Profil]) / 100 as "profilhøjde"
      from [Tabel].[dæk]) a
```

Comment: arh figured it out by using the one @vamsi posted and then using your `from (select [Dækstørelsen], ([brede] * [Profil]) / 100 as "profilhøjde"` in it